# Photoshop horizontal position of reference point

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have three images that I want to align. I have tried to set the x value of the horizontal position reference point, and Photoshop changes the value of one of my images by .5 px after every time I change it. The other two images will stay at the correct value, but the x value continues to change on the third image. I have tried toggling the relative positioning for reference point. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe if you add some images it might help us understand the concept and exactly where in the interface this is being reset.

Comment: I got it thanks - I ended up altering the layers and then aligning them by the bottom edges and it seemed to fix the problem.  Thank you for your comment though!

Comment: One thing that helps is if you can write the solution on the site so others, who might have this problem, can have a solution to use.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I ended up altering the layers and then aligning them by the bottom edges and it seemed to fix the problem.